# Firebase Email Verification is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my code user is created but Email Verification is not working.
Here is my code:

```
const signup = () => {
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // send verification mail.
      userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
      //auth.signOut();
      alert("Email sent");
    })
    .catch(alert);
}
```

Comment: Didi you check the spam folder of your mailbox?

Comment: yes, I have checked my spam folder but no mail is there.

Comment: The `sendEmailVerification()` returns a `Promise` but you are not waiting for it to resolve and `alert()` blocks the code execution . Try using `await` before that statement and making the function async like  ` .then(async (userCredential)=>`. Also try using `console.log("Email sent")` instead of the alert.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the `sendEmailVerification` promise to complete before showing the "Email sent" alert as it blocks the thread and prevents the `sendEmailVerification` from doing what it needs to.

```
const signup = () => {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // send verification mail.
        return userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
      })
      .then(() => alert("Email sent"))
      .catch((err) => alert(err));
}
```

**Note:** Take care in where you call `signup` as the browser may be reloading the page before any of the above steps complete because you aren't chaining the Promises. Either return `false` to the caller (to prevent the `form` element submitting) or the `Promise` chain to the caller (to handle success/failure of the actions).